# Winterbash 2016 - Yay or Nay? Hats!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

So the Winterbash season is upon us already (still feels weird when it's summer in Australia), and we need to vote on whether travel.SE gets it. Please vote accordingly below.

For everyone who wasn't here last year - for a few weeks in late December and early January you can earn "hats" (fun images you can add to your profile picture) for different activities on the site (last year: http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015). There's usually a bit of competition to find the best hats (some are secret, some are difficult to earn), and the most hats out there ;)

Comment: It seems like the choice has always been Hats or Nohats, but when you look at their platforms and record, aside from having or not having hats, the two parties are basically identical: mindcorrosive vs. mindcorrosive, RoflcoptrException vs RoflcoptrException. And now, no offense, it's Mark Mayo vs Mark Mayo— neither of whom even live in a part of the world where it's winter. No wonder the electorate is disillusioned. So I decline to side either with *I'm With Hats* or with *Make Hatlessness Great Again*. I guess I'll have to write someone in.

Comment: @choster welcome to the meritocracy ;)

Comment: Finally the hats are back again!

Comment: Which of the candidates had their own private email server?

Comment: @ZachLipton all of them ;) But I only store pictures of cats. Probably.

Comment: Cat pictures i.e. ones of the Chief Mouser to the Cabinet Office? That makes you suspicious!

Comment: By the way, I’m surprised this question didn’t attract any close votes yet!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because @Jan thinks it should have close votes.

Comment: Why are we even asking this question?! Bring on the hats!

Comment: I asked Neanderthal to come back and join the hat thingie. He scored 2nd place last year.  I won't repeat his answer here because flags would be raised. So for myself, I'm in. Count me as an enthusiastic consumer of hat mystique and hat glory.

Comment: Erm... what is Winterbash? Some context to this question might be good.

Comment: @FighterJet - good question. You earn hats (some secret, some detailed) for different activities on the site (last year: http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015).  There's usually a bit of competition to find the best hats, and most hats out there ;)

Comment: @pnuts featured posts timeout on their own, but good point, removed

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, yes, give me hats and give them to me now!

Comment: Where the hell are the hats?! It's cold here.

Comment: @JoErNanO they're here now, good luck ;)

Answer (score 6):

Hats are nice but we should be getting sleighs too!  Or something!

Answer (score 4):

Take your stupid hats and leave. I'm here to answer travel questions, not win virtual fashion accessories.

Comment: As an FYI for anyone vehemently anti-hats: there's usually an option for individual users to opt out of all the hat-related tomfoolery. If I remember right there's usually a link "I hate hats" that appears on the temporary hat-related inbox, which turns it all off for that user

Comment: @user568458 correct, that will exist again this year.

Comment: Why, no, everyone loves hats!